# DELETE query with DELETE query

Tags: mysql

I have lil doubt of mysql query.
I am trying to delete some row while using SELECT query. But unable to do that.
Anyone knows how to do this?

What I tried:

(one stmt):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_sub_category WHERE iSubCategoryID=13; 
DELETE FROM tbl_sub_category WHERE iSubCategoryID=14; 
SELECT * FROM tbl_sub_category order by iOrder ASC;
```

I dont know if these 3 queries can work together or not. I am using xampp for this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve???

Comment: I know this question seems crazy but i am just curious that whether it is possible or not to run 3 queries in single statement.

Comment: Sure you can do multi-queries in most environments. But that returns 2 resultsets and yours has to be able to consume them. A stored proc is another possibility but you still have 2 coming back.

Comment: @Drew What exactly should I do to get this working?

Comment: I would independently just do the delete first as there is no interference. Then determine why you want 2 resultsets coming back from the 2 selects. Then tell us what your programming language is

Comment: MySQL installed on server must be configured as allow running multi-queries . AND REMEMBER Sending queries can be less secure than sending one query. Take a Look at this http://www.dummies.com/programming/databases/how-to-send-multiple-queries-to-the-mysql-server/

Comment: @Mostafa MySQL allows multiple queries in a single script. This is not a configurable thing.

Comment: Yeah I was a bit confused by that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible! But instead of using `mysqli_qyery` you should use mysqli_multi_query. Take a look at the [php official site](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)

Comment: I am trying to run on xampp. I am not using php integration. I am just trying some queries.